# Puzzled with the workings of these variable assignments?

Tags: javascript

Tried to figure out the working logic behind the results. I couldn't.

Could someone please help explain how Javascript works the output of each of the 4 situations and the reason behind it?

I think the 1st and 2nd are similar situations.

Thanks

```js
var num = (1, 2, 3);    // num = 3 (last number returned, No error generated)
   console.log(num)

y = (1, 2, 3);          // y = 3  (last number returned, No error generated)
   console.log(y)

z = 1, 2, 3;            // z = 1  (first number returned, No error generated)
   console.log(z)

// Uncomment the following to run: (gives an error)

//var m = 1, 2, 3;        // Error: Unexpected number
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `var num = (1, 2, 3);` `num` is being set to the value of the final expression in the set. It's like a shorthand to evaluate multiple expressions and return the last value.

`y = (1, 2, 3);` is the same thing when you're at top level scope.

`z = 1, 2, 3;` is three expressions, `z = 1`, `2`, and `3`. `z` is set to 1, but if you logged the output of that line, you'd get 3.

`var m = 1, 2, 3;` is a syntax error because in this situation, the interpreter is expecting a single var pattern like `var m = 1, n = 2, o = 3`.

Comment: "`var m = 1, 2, 3;` throws an error because it conflicts with the expected use of the of the comma operator after `var`." – No, it is a syntax error precisely because it it *not* the comma operator here.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I changed the wording to reflect that the commas in a single var pattern are not called comma operators.

Answer (score 3):

Your first three snippets are all basically the same. They demonstrate usage of the *Comma Operator*.

[The *Comma Operator*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-comma-operator) `a, b` first evaluates `a` and throws away the result, then evaluates `b` and returns the result. It is left-associative, so `a, b, c` is the same as `(a, b), c`.

Observe:

```js
const foo = () => { console.log("foo"); return 23; };
const bar = () => { console.log("bar"); return 42; };
const qux = () => { console.log("qux"); return 99; };

console.log((foo(), bar()));
// foo
// bar
// 42

console.log((foo(), bar(), qux()));
// foo
// bar
// qux
// 99
```

Note that I could have written the three functions like this, but of course it doesn't make much sense to use the Comma Operator while trying to explain it:

```js
const foo = () => (console.log("foo"), 23);
const bar = () => (console.log("bar"), 42);
const qux = () => (console.log("qux"), 99);

console.log((foo(), bar(), qux()));
// foo
// bar
// qux
// 99
```

In your first snippet, you have a [*Variable Declaration* statement](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-variable-statement), which declares a variable, evaluates the initializer, and binds the value of the initializer to the variable. The initializer in this case is `1, 2, 3`, which is equivalent to `(1, 2), 3`. So, it will evaluate `1`, throw away the result, evaluate `2` return the result `2` as the result of evaluating the sub-expression `1, 2` but then immediately throw it away, evaluate `3` and return the result `3` as the result of the evaluation.

Therefore, it binds the value `3` to the variable `num`.

The second snippet is exactly the same, except it is an [*Assignment Expression*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-assignment-operators), not a Variable Declaration, i.e. in Strict Mode, it will assign to a variable named `y` that was previously declared with `let` or `var` and error out with a static error otherwise. In Loose Mode, it will assign to a variable named `y` that was previously declared with `let` or `var`, or to a property named `y` of the global implicit object otherwise.

The evaluation of the right-hand-side of the assignment is exactly the same as above.

Snippet #3 uses again the Comma Operator. The Comma Operator has higher precedence than the Assignment Operator (the way ECMAScript is specified, it does not contain a simple operator precedence table, rather, the precedence is implicit in the grammar, so you'll either have to [read the entire grammar](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-grammar-summary) or believe me), so your snippet #3 is equivalent to

```js
((z = 1), 2), 3;
```

Again, it works just the same as snippets #1 and #2: first, the expression `z = 1` is evaluated (which has the side-effect of assigning `1` to `z`) and the result is thrown away, then the expression `2` is evaluated and the result is thrown away, then the expression `3` is evaluated, and the result is returned.

So, the result of the entire expression is `3`, but since that result is not assigned to anything, not returned, not printed, it is simply thrown away. All that is left is the side-effect that happened while evaluating the first expression, namely assigning `1` to `z`.

The last expression is different, because it does not demonstrate the use of the Comma Operator. It is, again, a Variable Declaration, just like snippet #1. A Variable Declaration basically is a list of comma-separated identifiers with optional initializers. The reason you get an error here, is that `2` is not a valid identifier for a variable.

Observe:

```js
var n = 1, o, p;
// Declares variables `n`, `o`, `p`, initializes `n` to `1`.

console.log(n, o, p);
// 1 undefined undefined
```

Now, for comparison, your snippet #4 is *ecactly the same*:

```js
var m = 1, 2, 3;
// Declares variables `m`, `2`, `3`, but `2` and `3` are not legal names.
```

The major difference between this snippet #4 and the other three is that the comma means *a completely different thing* here. In snippets #1 to #3, it is the *Comma Operator*, whereas in snippet #4, it is part of the Variable Declaration syntax.

There are other places where the comma can mean something different, for example parameter lists (`function foo(a, b, c)` or `(a, b, c) => bla`) or argument lists (`foo(1, 2, 3)`). In both cases, the comma is not the Comma Operator but part of the parameter list or argument list syntax to separate the parameters or arguments.

Observe:

```js
console.log(1, 2, 3);
// 1 2 3

console.log((1, 2, 3));
// 3
```